# Play Music Behind App?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I recently released my app on the app store and one of my friends noticed that he couldnt listen to his music and play the game at the same time because each time the scene switched the music was cut out. What kind of code would I use to fix this so people can play their own music in the background?

Comment: you need to not use skaction playsound for a start

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [ObjectAL](http://kstenerud.github.io/ObjectAL-for-iPhone/) this functionality is as simple as:

[OALSimpleAudio sharedInstance].allowIpod = YES;

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into AVAudioSession. It provides the audio sessions categories which you can use to specify what should happen in the relationship between your sounds and other sounds.